# NP-completeness of crossword puzzle

Tags: np-complete

How to prove that this crossword puzzle is NP-complete?

- We have an instance of crosswords in a square grid $G$ ​​of size $m \times m$.
- We have a set of black boxes $N$.
- We have a dictionary of words  $D \subseteq\Sigma^{\ast}$, where $\Sigma$ is a finite alphabet.

The question is whether there is a way to fill in the white boxes ($G\setminus N$) so that all the horizontal and vertical words belong to $D$. Here we suppose $|\Sigma|\geq 3$.

Also note that the reduction should not create a dictionary that is too large.

Comment: You can reduce some version of Planar SAT to your problem. It would require some work.

Comment: I think it's possible to use 3-SAT here, but how to do it?

Comment: Why do you think it’s possible? Somebody told you?

Comment: No, I just know that all NP-complete problems get reduced to 3-SAT

Comment: Right, but sometimes there isn’t any simple direct reduction.

Comment: Right, So how to prove that, this problem is NP?

Comment: It’s easy to see that the problem is in NP. The difficult part is showing that it’s NP-hard.